# Lack of 'Raspi-config'

Tags: raspbian

I've just started my Raspberry Pi for the first time (Model B Revision 1.0, Raspbian on a card from RS).

At no stage was I presented with the Raspi-config menu. I've tried to access it using the `sudo raspi-config` command, but I get the message "command not found".

I've also tried updating the OS using `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` but get messages containing "failed to fetch...".

Is there any way of updating my OS using the existing image I have on the SD card from RS, or do I need to get a brand new image and start again using a fresh SD card?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like the cards RS is shipping don't have `raspi-config` installed. You can install it from the repository using `sudo apt-get install raspi-config` (you may have to run `sudo apt-get update` first. The package is in the `http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/` repository.

As for the "failed to fetch..." error message when running `sudo apt-get update`, this is a networking issue, as the Pi isn't able to connect to the repository.

If you can get networking working, you can grab the script and any OS updates without wiping the card and writing a new image.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this after doing a debootstrap. Here's the solution:

1. Add this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

- `deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main`

2. Run these commands:

- `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 7FA3303E`
- `apt-get update`
- `apt-get install raspi-config`

Answer (score 0):

Can you see it when you pop your SD card into a card reader in windows?

I had a similar problem with mine and i couldn't even see the 56MB partition in windows so I just downloaded the latest OS and reflashed as per the instructions on the Pi website.  After that the config file was there in windows and showed on first boot on the Pi

Answer (score 0):

From: [How to use raspistill on Ubuntu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37359/how-to-use-raspistill-on-ubuntu)

```
apt-get install libnewt0.52 whiptail parted triggerhappy lua5.1 alsa-utils -y
wget https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20180406+1_all.deb -P /tmp
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/raspi-config_20180406+1_all.deb
```

Comment: All answer on Stack-exchange require some sort of description / explanation as to what code does.