# How to use raspistill on Ubuntu

Tags: camera, raspicam

I have Ubuntu 14 installed on my Raspberry Pi 2, and I'm trying to access the camera, but all the instructions assume raspistill is available, but that only seems to be compiled for Raspbian. How do you access the Raspberry Pi camera from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I seem to be the only person in the entire world who wants to use a regular Linux distro on the RPi, since I could find very little documentation on how to setup the camera from scratch, but in case someone else wants to use the Raspberry Pi camera on Ubuntu or any other distro besides Raspbian, here's how you do it.

1. Enable kernel/firmware settings required by the camera:

   ```
   sudo bash -c "echo 'start_x=1' >> /boot/config.txt"
   sudo bash -c "echo 'gpu_mem=128' >> /boot/config.txt"
   ```

   Note, in the Ubuntu ARM image I used, these settings didn't exist in /boot/config.txt, so I can simply append them. If you've already added the variables, but with different values, you may need to edit them instead of appending.
2. Install `rpi-update` and update the firmware

   If you're using a brand-new RPi, you'll almost certainly need to update the firmware, because whatever the factory installs is ancient:

   ```
   curl -L --output /usr/bin/rpi-update https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update && chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-update
   sudo rpi-update
   ```

   Note, without these step, I was getting the infamous error:

   > ```
   > mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component 'vc.ril.camera'
   > mmal: Failed to create camera component
   > mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
   > mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
   > ```
3. Install userland binaries (e.g. raspistill):

   > ```
   > sudo apt install cmake
   > git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland.git
   > cd userland
   > ./buildme # or "./buildme --aarch64" for 64-bit OS
   > touch ~/.bash_aliases
   > echo -e 'PATH=$PATH:/opt/vc/bin\nexport PATH' >> ~/.bash_aliases
   > echo -e 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/vc/lib\nexport LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bash_aliases
   > source ~/.bashrc
   > ldconfig
   > ```
4. Give non-root users access to the camera device:

   ```
   echo 'SUBSYSTEM==\"vchiq\",GROUP=\"video\",MODE=\"0660\"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/10-vchiq-permissions.rules
   usermod -a -G video ubuntu
   ```

   Without these, I was getting the error:

   > ```
   > failed to open vchiq instance
   > ```
5. Reboot to make all changes take effect

   ```
   sudo reboot now
   ```

After these steps, `raspistill -o cam.jpg` correctly captured video input for me on a Raspberry Pi 2 running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Quick question: which Ubuntu variant was this on, the Ubuntu MATE environment, Ubuntu Snappy Core, or something else? I'm interested as I should probably link to this from the picamera FAQ (I can imagine this might come up a bit in the future)

Comment: @DaveJones, I'm using the community-maintained image of Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS built specifically for the Raspberry Pi. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Comment: i am sorry to bother but did you mean
sudo bash -c "echo 'start_x=1' >> /boot/config.txt"
instead of
sudo base -c "echo 'start_x=1' >> /boot/config.txt" ?

Comment: @ShuoyuanXu, Yep, good catch.

Comment: You can skip #3 and just use the VideoCore packages: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-raspi2/ppa; sudo apt-get install libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi-dev` See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#VideoCore

Answer (score 1):

On a new Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu Mate 16.04.2 installed all I needed to do was:

```
sudo rpi-update
sudo raspi-config
#Select 3 Interface Options then P1 to enable the camera
shutdown -r now
```

When it restarted both raspistill and cheese started working (after making sure the resolution was adjusted to something smaller).

Answer (score 0):

As per this forum [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=107960&p=744233), most likely path is not being setup. You can check if utility is installed perfectly by checking `sudo /opt/vc/bin/raspistill -o output.jpg`. If it works perfectly, you need to add `/opt/vc/bin` location to path as it is not included by default in ubuntu.

How to do it ?

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir`

where, `/path/to/dir` in this case is `/opt/vc/bin`.

Hope it helps.