# How to use raspistill on a Raspberry Pi 3 from Ubuntu

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, ubuntu

How do you enable the camera module in Ubuntu 16.04 running on a Raspberry Pi 3?

This is similar to [my earlier question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37387/29103), except where that was for the Raspberry Pi 2, this is for the 3.

I ran through the same procedure I documented there, but even though all steps ran successfully, and the command `vcgencmd get_camera` reports:

```
supported=1 detected=1
```

attempting to run `raspistill --nopreview --output image.jpg` results in the error:

```
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component 'vc.camera_info'
mmal: Failed to create camera_info component
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component 'vc.ril.camera'
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I re-ran `sudo rpi-udpate`, re-checked by settings in `/boot/config.txt` but everything looks right. I had previously gotten the camera working under Raspbian on the Pi3, and I haven't changed any wiring since replacing the SD card with an image of Ubuntu 16, so the I'm certain it's a software issue. What's different with Ubuntu? What can I do to diagnose and fix this problem?

```
$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   10340  2
hci_uart               17943  1
btbcm                   5929  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             326105  22 bnep,btbcm,hci_uart
binfmt_misc             6388  1
snd_usb_audio         118608  0
snd_hwdep               5727  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_usbmidi_lib        19801  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_rawmidi            18516  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
evdev                  11396  0
snd_seq_device          3621  1 snd_rawmidi
brcmfmac              186339  0
brcmutil                5661  1 brcmfmac
cdc_acm                17370  0
cfg80211              427855  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 16037  6 cfg80211,bluetooth
bcm2835_gpiomem         3040  0
bcm2835_wdt             3225  0
uio_pdrv_genirq         3164  0
uio                     8000  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
snd_bcm2835            20447  0
snd_pcm                75762  2 snd_bcm2835,snd_usb_audio
snd_timer              19288  1 snd_pcm
snd                    51908  8 snd_bcm2835,snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device
ipv6                  347530  24

$ cat /boot/config.txt | grep -v '^#' | grep '.'
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
start_x=1
gpu_mem=256

$ uname -a
Linux localhost 4.4.23-v7+ #913 SMP Tue Oct 4 14:16:19 BST 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

After I enabled `start_debug=1` in my `/boot/config.txt`, now `sudo vcdbg log assert` shows:

```
002702.229: assert( source ) failed; ../../../../../middleware/confzilla/cp_front_fdt.c::cp_front_fdt_load_builtin line 115 rev c844c61
vcdbg_ctx_get_dump_stack: dump_stack failed
----------------
003569.708: assert( card not initialised ) failed; ../../../../../filesystem/media/sdcard/sdcard.c::sdhost_close line 1045 rev c844c61
vcdbg_ctx_get_dump_stack: dump_stack failed
----------------
```

Edit: I'm not entirely sure what happened, but now it's working. In case anyone else runs into this, here's what I did.

I tried downgrading my firmware to a version from Oct 2015. That failed and caused by Pi to show the Rainbow Screen of Death. However, I was able to use rpi-update from my laptop to revert the firmware on the SD card, to get it to boot again.

Another issue I was having was insanely long boot times when unplugged from ethernet. I fixed this by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` and changing eth0's entry from auto to manual. I also fixed a problem with eth0 being renamed to enx*, which might have been confusing network startup.

I was also seeing a boot up error from the "Load System Module" service. Looking at the log showed it was trying to load kernel module `bcm2808_rng` which didn't exist. Researching this error found that this module is for the Raspberry Pi 2, and has been removed and replaced with the module `bcm2835_rng`. Modifying the file '/etc/modules-load.d/rpi2.conf' and replacing the old module name with the new one fixed that error.

The docs for installing raspistill on Ubuntu had me cloning and building the `https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland.git` repo. I was previously doing this from inside `/tmp`. I changed this to `~`, incase the build was saving important files in `/tmp` which were then being lost after reboot.

After a few reboots, I again tested raspistill, and it worked. I'm not sure if any of those changes were fixes, or if I just scared away some gremlins, but I've rebooted a few times and raspistill is now working reliably.

I re-ran the shell commands I posted earlier, so see what's changed, and everything was the same except for the lsmod output. It shows the exact same kernel modules, but where the `evdev` module was listed as being used by 0 other modules, it nows shows it's being used by 2 other modules, although it doesn't list those module's names.

Comment: The error you were getting indicates the firmware wasn't camera enabled so my guess would be *something* went wrong with the initial `rpi-update` attempt (though I couldn't say what). Anyway, glad to hear it's working again - I must give the camera a whirl under Ubuntu sometime

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same problem as you did, also by painfully executed your steps for the RPi2 found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37387).

I did not go through your boot problems as I only downgraded (using `rpi-update`) from `840a496a84e9e76ee3aef42918eecac06bd7f610` to `667cfabe63bc663383559ef88317e86f9bd41e45` (14 days older). The sha hashes/versions can be found [here](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-firmware/commits/master).

After the upgrade (and a reboot) `raspistill -o cam.jpg` all of a sudden worked.

I also tried to upgrade do the latest firmware version (`840a496a84e9e76ee3aef42918eecac06bd7f610`) again, and - surprise - everything still works.

Besides that, I only enabled boot logging as suggested by you, but I did not change anything otherwise. (I also didn't had `bcm2835_rng` in my `/etc/modules-load.d/rpi2.conf`; ethernet was connected all the time).

So the solution seems to be:

- Follow @Cerin's [steps for the RPi 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37387)
- Try to run `raspistill -o cam.jpg`, if it fails, downgrade by using *for example* `sudo rpi-update 667cfabe63bc663383559ef88317e86f9bd41e45`
- Reboot and try `raspistill -o cam.jpg`, again.

So now that I got raspistill working, gstreamer still refuses to run, but that's not subject of this thread...

`$ gst-launch-1.0 rpicamsrc bitrate=1000000 \
     ! 'video/x-h264,width=640,height=480' \
     ! h264parse \
     ! queue \
     ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 \
     ! gdppay \
     ! udpsink host=10.0.0.92 port=5600
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not find component 'vc.ril.camera'
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRpiCamSrc:rpicamsrc0: GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3354): gst_base_src_start (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRpiCamSrc:rpicamsrc0:
Failed to start
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...`