# Can't run raspistill on Ubuntu 20.04 (rpi-4)

Tags: pi-4, raspicam, ubuntu

**My system**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
Raspberry: Raspberry 4B
Raspberry Camera: V2.1
```

`$ uname -a`:

```
Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-1022-raspi #25-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 15 13:31:49 UTC 2020 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

`$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update`:

```
BCM2711 detected
Dedicated VL805 EEPROM detected
BOOTLOADER: up-to-date
CURRENT: Thu 03 Sep 2020 12:11:43 PM UTC (1599135103)
 LATEST: Thu 03 Sep 2020 12:11:43 PM UTC (1599135103)
 FW DIR: /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical
VL805: up-to-date
CURRENT: 000138a1
 LATEST: 000138a1
```

`$ vcgencmd get_camera`:

```
supported=0 detected=0
```

`$ groups ubuntu`:

```
ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev lxd i2c gpio spi
```

Last line of `$ sudo rpi-update` is `*** Your firmware is already up to date`

**The problem**

When I run `raspistill -o test.jpg` I get

```
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not enabled in this build. Try running "sudo raspi-config" and ensure that "camera" has been enabled
```

I then run `sudo raspi-config` and enable the camera interface. Reboot try again but same error.

**What I've done**

I followed the prompts by Cerin in this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37359/how-to-use-raspistill-on-ubuntu?r=SearchResults).

`/boot/config.txt` contains

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

For good measure my `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt` contains

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

`/etc/udev/rules.d/10-vchiq-permissions.rules` does not exist on my system so in `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/local.rules` I included

```
SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq", GROUP="video", MODE="0660"
```

Then in the command line `$ sudo usermod -aG video ubuntu`

Finally I double checked the physical connection. Set up of the camera looks no different to [here](https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-23941-315795/raspi%2Bcam.jpg)

**Desired outcome**
I want to take images with the camera using ```raspistill``. Please lend me your help!!!

Comment: Install Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: For your information, I summarized all the steps here: https://zengliyang.wordpress.com/2021/01/04/raspberry-pi-4b-ubuntu-20-04-camera/
Hope it can help you.